# Subview goes out of screen bounds iOS (Auto layout)

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, autolayout

I am developing a component in a separate xib file which I then add to my controller. The issue is that the trailing side of my inner containers goes out of bounds of my outer container. To be more precise my subview width fits into my view controller, but elements inside subview are going out of that container. The constraints are all set to 0 (top, bottom, trailing, leading). I have set clip subviews to true for the container. Images below demonstrate the problem. Right label on the first image goes out of container constraints when i build the app. The same will be for every element. I have played with the trailing constraint and if I set it to -40 the label appears on the screen however I feel that there has to be a better solution.

[image: Storyboard file]
[image: Application build]

The size class that i'm using is Compact:Regular.

Answer (score 0):

Actualy, you came up with the right solution. For components like labels or image views (components, that can determine their sizes implicitly based on content), it is only necessary to set one constraint in each dimension. In your situation, it should be enough to set trailing and, for example, center Y of `label`. The rest will be dependent on label content itself

**Update**

Take a look [Apple's guide on autolayout](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/ViewswithIntrinsicContentSize.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010853-CH13-SW1) and [Intrinsic Content Size](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/AnatomyofaConstraint.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010853-CH9-SW21)

Comment: Yes, but the problem I have is that when I set trailing to 0 it's actually not 0 but the label goes from the screen (like if you set it to -20 or something). This wouldn't be a problem if I were to assemble my elements from left to right, but I need the label to be pined to the right edge of the screen.

Comment: In that case, problem lies elsewhere, not in trailing constraint. What else constraints do you have?

Comment: I've managed to fix it by adding a subview through code instead of storyboard. I couldn't find another solution.

Comment: Like I said, problem lies somewhere in the way you create constraints hierarchy in storyboard. Didn't you checked property "Remove at build time"?

Comment: I didn't change constraints at all, I just removed the class from view in stroyboard and added it through code. For some reason the width of my inner container (subview) was bigger than the container. Once I added it through code it was properly calculated based on the width of the screen.